# how to use firebase authentication with multiple login methods and role based authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm creating a react.js app as nodejs as backend, i want to use these authentication methods login with email/password, login with google and login with phone, now i want to keep users unique as when a user signs up with any of them, i will take the other details also, like when user signs up with email/password, then i will also take user phone number and i dont want user to create another account with that phone number by using login with phone method.

and the second issue is my app has 3 user roles, user, sales and admin. each user has different sign up forms, and when a user with email sign up as sales and i also want to enable that user to sign up as user with same email, now as i use firebase sdk in react app, it throws error as user already exists.

what can be the resolution for this issue with firebase authentication and i want users to be unique and also i want to enable role based authentication.
i'm using firestore as my database

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep users unique as when a user signs up with any of the
> authentication methods, i.e. login with email/password, login with
> google and login with phone

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#unlink-an-auth-provider-from-a-user-account), "You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in". See also the doc for the [`linkWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#linkwithcredential) and [`linkWithPhoneNumber()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#linkwithphonenumber) methods.

> My app has 3 user roles, user, sales and admin. Each user has
> different sign up forms, and [...] I want to enable a user to sign up
> as different roles.

You can use a role-based access control strategy based on [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) (you can add several claims, one for each role) or on [Firestore documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access). But you'll have, in your app, to implement yourself the mechanism for the user to choose the role (you mention "different sign up forms" in your question) and the corresponding GUI displaying.

Comment: Hey @UdayKiran, did you have the time to look at my answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: yeah, i thank you @renaud. this answers my question.